# Cannot read property 'getFirstExists' of undefined

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

I'm creating an invader-like game using Phaser HTML5 game engine.

Run into this `Cannot read property 'getFirstExists' of undefined` error when I'm trying to add the collision test for the 'ship' and the 'enemies'...

I've already spent two days on it and still no clues. :(

Please help. Thank you.

```
var play = function(game) {}

play.prototype = {
    create: function(){
      ....
        // Add an explosion group
        this.explosions = this.game.add.group();
        this.explosions.enableBody = true;
        this.explosions.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
        this.explosions.createMultiple(15, 'explosion');
        this.explosions.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
        this.explosions.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5);
        this.explosions.forEach( function(explosion) {
          explosion.animations.add('explosion', [0, 1, 2], 10 , false);
        });
    },

    update: function(){
      ....
        this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.ship, this.enemyGroupSizeL,     this.shipCollision, null, this);
    },

    shipCollision: function(s, e) {
        this.explosion = this.explosions.getFirstExists(false); // ERROR
        this.explosion.reset(e.body.x + e.body.halfWidth, e.body.y + e.body.halfHeight);
        this.explosion.body.velocity.y = e.body.velocity.y;
        this.explosion.alpha = 0.7;
        this.explosion.play('explosion', 30, false, true);
        e.kill();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't suppose you can share more of your code or link to your game? Comparing this with a working example from a tutorial that's very similar, I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted.

Comment: I also don't see anything wrong with this code, but you could try setting a `debugger;` as first line of the `shipCollision()` function. Then open the developer tools ctrl+shift+J to see what is the value of `this` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I use typescript to make games in Phaser. I think one of reason can be that Phaser engine call Update function (auto invoke) before the explosion object is created.

Add

```
if(this.explosion !+ undefined)
```

before

```
this.game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.ship, this.enemyGroupSizeL, this.shipCollision, null, this);
```

in your update function.